# Running Application with Wine on Text Console Only (no x server started)

Tags: wine

I'd like to use a windows **console** application on a linux server (centos 6) via wine. It's an image generation tool. The application works fine as long as I'm running it via a graphic desktop (gnome or KDE) but with only the console available (as it's needed for the server scenario) the application starts and does nearly everything needed, but the generated images are completely black. Is there any possibility to configure wine that it will run my program on the text console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it using a virtual frame buffer, such as [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).